# Django include template along with its css

Tags: django, inheritance, django-templates, include

I am trying to include a template - header.html into the main.html file. The header.html has its own css file. I have one choice- to link the css into the head of header.html and then include it. But it makes the code looks messier with many html tags in the same document. For instance, if I need to include another footer.html, again additional html tags will come to the main.html.

Another option is to simply put all the styles into one main.css file and include that in the base.html. But again it makes main.css harder to edit.

Is there any better solutions?

Thanks

Comment: One way is to make reusable class and id. It will take time first but can be helpful afterwards. Make similar kind of class for both header and footer. Add the common css file to static folder and import into base html. For body add extend tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder as templates under root directory of your project and add below line in settings.py file to define the template path.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], #mainly this line
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATIC = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

After it make `base.html` file  and enter all the js and css file over here. That will reflect to all the project.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
    <title>Test </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/small.png' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.css' %}" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/responsive.css' %}" type="text/css" />
    <!-- more css files -->
  </head>
  <body>
      {% block pagecontent %}
      {% endblock %}

  </body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/asset/jquery-2.1.3.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="static 'custom.js' %}"></script>
 <!-- more js files -->
</html>
```

Comment: Screenshots aren't any more useful in answers than they are in questions. Post code here as text.

Comment: Anoop, Thanks for the reply. However, the following is my concern. The base.html is in the main (root) directory whereas the main.html is in another directory (Main). Here, the director 'Main' has all the statics for main.html. However, when I extend base.html since it does not have any CSS files to style the main, my challenge is to find a way to include the CSS in the base.html. As we know, the base.html takes the static files from its root directory, how can I make sure, base.html has all the CSS needed for main.html

Comment: I already mentioned about the templates folder. Try to  create your base.html under templates directory under root as shown in this screenshot https://prnt.sc/lk6jkh and when you extend the base file from templates directory It will include all the statics file to all the html files